# Spring Security and Single Page Applications

Tags: spring, angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security, single-page-application

My application will be:
- Single Page App (say in angular/backbone)
- Spring MVC based Server.

I find many examples about using Spring-Security where the login page, logout page etc.. are all HTMLs. And Spring Security directs to appropriate pages based on Session State.

But in my case the login/logout page will be in JavaScript - All interaction with the server for login/logout is over HTTP(REST style URLs), and response JSON. There is no HTML in play here.

**Question**
How can i use Spring Security in this case? In other words - How can i expose login/logout behavior as a API?

Since the front end is Browser based app... i guess usual cookies etc. should still work for identifying session.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Cookies still work in your cases. But you need to tap on the ajax urls instead of normal urls. I had an experience with a mobile based - single page application and I managed to do it with a grails backend. When logging in tap on /j_spring_security_check?ajax=true if http response is 302 and it redirects you to /login/ajaxSuccess it means that you have logged in successfully. Otherwise you failed to login.

Comment: how can you manage angular templates, if its was already cached?

Comment: how can you manage situation, if users has different permission for same url (same angular template)

Comment: You think of loading templates using ajax and protecting the url by spring security ?
In my opinion this should be defined in your angular code not using spring security. In your angular scope you need to get the user details and the role

Comment: if you have 2-5 roles,and few urls -it's possible ok for some applications.but if your application has 20-50 roles (i do not say about 2-10 templates depends on role) it will be hard to manage and support. And one time if someone will say _**"we should not use 10 roles, but we'll get 5 new ones"**_ - **it will be hell** because of UI logic integration. If you'll trust to UI manage roles - you'll lose flexibility. And any way following best practise you should **never give to UI information about important security parts**! UI should have as little logic as it possible. In perfect case - ZERO.